# Airflow - Getting "bytes" object has no attribute "module" error

Tags: python, airflow

I have a function that makes a request to a zip file and returns the contents as bytes. I want to integrate this function into an Airflow DAG, but I'm getting the following error message when I try to run the task :

```
ERROR - Failed to execute job 213 for task scrape ('bytes' object has no attribute '__module__'; 42409)
```

```
# Function to request a zip file and return its content
def run_scrape_latest_drug():
    response = requests.get(zip_file_url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.content
    data = scrape_latest_drug()
    return data

# Airflow DAG
with DAG("test_skip", start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
         schedule_interval="@daily", catchup=False) as dag:

    # Task to run the function and get the zip file content
    task_scrape = PythonOperator(
        task_id="scrape", python_callable=run_scrape_latest_drug
    )
```

Is there a solution for this problem?

expecting suggestions or solution

Comment: Does it succeed if you call `run_scrape_latest_drug()` directly? If not, please copy-paste the full output (multiline error message) to your question.

Comment: Yes, it does. it work perfectly fine when I called it directly @pts